# how to make my files appear in project navigator in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7.3

[image]

while I work on Xcode my project files and folders suddenly disappeared except these files.. if i search for a keyword its file will appear and  added to other files in  project navigator..how to show them again in  project navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this button is pressed. If it is blue, press on it.

[image: Recent files]

If toggled, it will only show recent files. You don't want that. You want to see all files.

Comment: Or -obviously- make sure that the "filter" textfield is empty :)